# Sql Connection string to my mdf database file

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

My `database.mdf` is in the same folder where my `application.exe` is. I searched other questions and found this way but after I start my program I get an error

[image: Screenshot]

```
string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\DATABASE1.MDF";

string strConnection = @"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename = [" + dbPath + "]; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True";
```

Comment: Have you tried to open *Management Studio* to check out if the database isn't already attached to local *SQL Server Express*?

Comment: its mdf and i can see its connect but my app wont connect cause address

Comment: Your app won't read a mdf file directly, you're using the *Sql Server Express* engine for this, and probably the issue is because the database is already attached. Try to detach the database from *Sql Server Express*

Comment: found soluation tnx for answer mr pontual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM found soluation . the problem was []

```
string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\DATABASE1.MDF";
        string strConnection =
            @"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename = " + dbPath + "; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True";
```